# Avoid forward redeclaration. Is it a good practice? Is it necessary?

Tags: c++

I am used to do forward declarations of classes like this:

```
// file 1
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP

class A
{
    ...
};

#endif

// file 2
#ifndef B_HPP
#define B_HPP

#ifndef A_HPP
class A;
#endif

class B
{

};

#endif
```

As you can see in `file 2`, I try to safe the forward declaration of `A`. So, it should not be possible to redeclare A.

I have seen a lot of code where they don't put the guards around the forward declarations.

I wanted to know if what I am doing is really necessary or if it adds some kind of safety. Would any of these approaches benefit compilation times more than the other? Which one would you use? Why?

Comment: I don't see a point unless there's circular references; just replace `#ifndef A_HPP ... #endif` with `#include "a.hpp"`. Any type of compilation time benefit is likely negligible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are NOT adding any safety. Declarations in C++ can be repeated any times you want, as long as they are all coherent.

Furthermore, this is not a good practice. I've never seen someone doing like that. Think what would happen if you move `A`'s definition from `a.hpp`: you should change all the scope guards around `A`'s forward declaration in all files. Life is already complicated enough.

Comment: What about compilation times. Wouldn't it take time to assure that declarations are coherent?

Comment: I don't think it adds so much time it worth caring about. BTW, wouldn't your check increase compile time too?

Comment: I don't know. Thanks for the concise answer.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to use the marco guard as compiler will know how to process both file.

No need to out the follow 3 lines in file2.h

```
#ifndef A_HPP
class A;
#endif
```

use the following line is already good enough

```
#include "file1.h"
```

**The concept of forward declaration**

forward declaration is used to notify compiler there is a class ( or struct or whatever type you want ) named as "A" when reading the file. but compiler knows the declaration is not specific here, but may be in the other file.

At that time, compiler will know:

1) OK, there is a class named as "A", I will remember it.

2) I dont know its size and detail. But if coder use only the A* (pointer of A), it is OK and I dont need to know the detail of A.

Forward declaration is useful. Especially classes are interrelated.

But, if the type name of A is not in sync between both files. g++ will fail to compile.

---

**Compilation time**

Forward declaration is also good to use as it save the compilation time.

If the file does not change, g++ will not re-compile again.

While the file 2 use only the forward declaration, so no matter how you change the file 1 or class A, file 2 will not be compile again.